# using FFMPEG to convert to MP4 with maximum browsers compatibilty

Tags: php, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-conversion

I'm converting from `WMV` to `FLV` using `FFMPEG`, and my problem is that the `FLV` videos are so big! the 15 minutes video's size ranges between 150MB and 1GB!
I'm using the following `FFMPEG` command to convert and split `WMV` videos :
`nohup nice -1 ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:15:00 -async 1 -i INPUT.WMV -acodec libmp3lame OUTPUT.FLV`
And I've tried converting to `MP4` before and the video size was much smaller than the `FLV` video.
So my questions are:

- Would the `MP4` videos have any
  compatibility issues browsers?
- Would it work on iPhone, iPad? (I
  know `FLV` videos doesn't work on
  iPhones or iPads)
- What is the best `FFMPEG` command to
  convert to `MP4` without losing the
  quality of the video?

Answer (score 1):

A few points...

1. Video size has to do with the bit rate, dimension, and codec.  It does not have anything to do with the container.
2. You can certainly expect 15 minutes of video to be large, assuming you want more than a postage stamp for viewing area.  This is normal.
3. Any time you re-compress something, you are going to lose quality.  There is no way around this.  You might be able to keep most quality by recompressing at a higher bitrate, but this defeats what you are trying to accomplish.

Bottom line, unless you need to, don't do it.  Simply encode your videos at the appropriate bitrate to begin with.

Comment: I've tried to change the bitrate of the video and had no luck

Comment: Is it because WMV video bitrate is variable?

Comment: Here is the ffmpeg command after setting the bitrate `ffmpeg -y -ss 00:01:00 -t 00:01:00 -async 1 -i INPUT.wmv -acodec libmp3lame -b 64k OUTPUT.flv` and here is the output that I get at while converting the video `frame=  377 fps= 14 q=31.0 Lsize=    2852kB time=60.42 bitrate= 386.7kbits/s` ... the bitrate is 387kbits!! why?!

Answer (score 1):

For converting any video to mp4, use:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i INPUT.wmv -vcodec libx264  -sameq OUTPUT.mp4
```

If the quality is too low on that then set the bitrate to be around what you want:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i INPUT.wmv -vcodec libx264  -b 500k OUTPUT.mp4
```

The output mp4 file plays in Flash, browsers that support H.264 MPEG4, iOS, and Android.